# Test for directive watch fails; only fired first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am attempting to pass a test for my angularjs directive using jasmine.

My directive simply takes what is passed into the attribute (as a one way binding) and replaces the elements text with that value. My directive also watches for changes in the value and updates the elements text accordingly:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        test: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.text(scope.test());

        scope.$watch('test', function (value) {
            console.log('WATCH FIRED!');
            element.text(scope.test());
        });
    }
};
```

My jasmine test attempts to set the value passed into the directive, then change it, and then checks to see if the elements text is different after changing the value:

```
it('should update when the model updates', function () {
    $scope.model = 'hello';
    $scope.$digest();
    var before = element.text();

    $scope.model = 'world';
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(element.text()).not.toEqual(before);
});
```

But the test fails everytime. In fact, the elements text is always 'hello' and never gets changed to 'world'.

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/UeUGE88LuQRgeo7I412p?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beacuse you are using one way binding in your directive (`&`) so changes to the model are not tracked. Try using two way binding `=` and it should work as expected.

> The & binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time. Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which contains a function call. Because of this, & bindings are ideal for binding callback functions to directive behaviors.

```
 ...
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            test: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.text(scope.text);

            scope.$watch('test', function (value) {
                console.log('WATCH FIRED!');
                element.text(scope.test);
            });
        }
    };
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JPtDeZgZrWcuVEv1JuXO?p=preview)**

Or you would need to do:-

```
       scope.$watch(function(){
            return scope.test();
        }, function (value) {
            console.log('WATCH FIRED!');
            element.text(scope.test);
         });
```

Comment: Switching my scope variable to use a two way binding does work, but why? I was under the impression that one way bindings meant that parent changes affected children (updating the scope variable updates the directives isolate scope variable), but child changes don't affect the parent (updating the directives isolate scope doesn't update the scopes variable)? Isn't the directives isolate scope a child scope of my test scope?

Comment: @DamirBojan no. isolated scope is not a child scope. It is isolated.. It doesn't do any prototype inheritance from parent scope. That is why we have "=" syntax for 2 way binding. Generally you use `&` to bind to a method on the parent scope... But it can be used for properties as well.. and value can be evaluated by applying  parenthesis as you did in your example. WHen you place `=` angular places a watch on both the properties so that updates happen bothways.

Comment: @DamirBojan Or you would need to do `scope.$watch(function(){
                return scope.test();
            }` because the properties are not watched unless you update it manually in your real time implementation.